# How to pass the results from one mysql query to another mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table where it has two columns, the first column has the stores names and the second column has the products names.
Each store has multiple products, and multiple stores can share the same product.

How can I Run READ only commands against this table so I get a distinct list of Stores and then query a list of products in each Store?

PS; I don't want to run any write operations in my sql db.
The end result should be something like:

```
----------------------
| Store | Product    |
----------------------
| Store1| Product1   |
| Store1| Product2   |
|   ..  |  ..        |
| Store2| Product1   |
| Store2| Product2   |
|   ..  |  ..        |
| Store3| Product1   |
| Store3| Product2   |
|   ..  |  ..        |
----------------------
```

The question was already Answered below, Here is the query that worked:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product,store 
FROM table_name 
WHERE store in (
SELECT DISTINCT store 
FROM table_name
);
```

Comment: this is what JOIN does

Comment: Do you want all that in one request ? can you show the sample output you want to have!!

Comment: I have 240 stores and over 10500 products, I need to loop over the store list and get one table that shows each store and its products.
I want to avoid looping over the store list in python and get products for each store.

Comment: Your desired result has two columns, store and product. You have described your  table as *"the first column has the stores names and the second column has the products names."*. As far as I can tell your table is already the same as your desired output. Can't you just select from it? If it is not the same as your desired output, are you able to post some sample data from your source table?

Comment: Definitely my table has a missive amount of columns, and for simplicity I mentioned two columns only. I can't post a sample of the source table since the info is confidential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand the nature of the result you want, but i imagine that you want a list of prodects per store. in that case you can use this requets

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE store in (SELECT DISTINCT store from table_name);
```

Comment: Thank you Amir, this worked like a charm
```
SELECT DISTINCT product,store FROM table_name WHERE store in (SELECT DISTINCT store from table_name); 
```

Comment: The query posted is exactly the same as `SELECT * FROM table_name`. Every store in `table_name` will also exist in `table_name` (since they are the same table), so the `WHERE` clause achieves nothing. Similarly if `SELECT DISTINCT product,store FROM table_name WHERE store in (SELECT DISTINCT store from table_name);` works, then `SELECT DISTINCT product,store FROM table_name` will also work.

Comment: Agree. where clause will be helpful if the stores are listed in another table.

Comment: @heshamnoaman you can mark the answer, to avoid upcoming comments.